# onmouseover show/ hide div and can select the text of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to Show and hide one tooltip on hover of an anchor. but tooltip should be there till my cursor on it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62bcr/)

```
$('#showReasonTip').mouseover(function(){
$(this).parent().find('#reasonTip').slideDown()}).mouseout(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('#reasonTip').slideUp()
    }
)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#showReasonTip').hover(function () {
        var $target = $('#reasonTip');
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }, function () {
        var $target = $('#reasonTip');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $($('#reasonTip')).hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4V5S9/)

Answer (score 2):

You should try using `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout` and that too on `#reasonTip` and not on `#showReasonTip`.

```
$('#showReasonTip').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('#reasonTip').slideDown()
});
$('#reasonTip').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('#reasonTip').slideUp()
});
```

[Here's the modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/62bcr/5/) with a small change in your code.

Comment: You can untick it or [change the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon) if you want or leave it as it is.